# Polyline and Polygon of fabricjs and Closed Line of KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, fabricjs

What is the difference between fabric's Polygon and Polyline class? I think except for closed end there is no difference?

Also I wanted to draw closed area similar to Kinetic.Line behavior but for FabricJS.

I have added a demo for this at http://jsbin.com/hubunu/1/edit

For me output of Kineticjs is correct. I want similar in FabricJS.

[image]

Comment: You have answered your own question: "except for closed end there is no difference".  You can use `.moveTo` to change the z-index on your line so that it is drawn on top of your gold semi-circle.

Comment: @markE - Its not about z-index but top of that item.

Answer (score 0):

This was easy. originX and originY took some time for me to understand. To get expected result for above problem. I found out minimum x and minimum y of polygon points. Set left and top of polygon to minimum X and minimum Y respectively.

However edge of KineticJS(expected) are more sharper than that of FabricJS.

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/hubunu/3/edit

[image]